# jQuery Zebra Striping: Skip First Row

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I need some help with zebra striping a table using jQuery. I want the first table row to be red and then zebra stripe the rest of the rows.

I can make the first table row red using:

```
$("#my_table tbody tr:even").addClass("stripeRed");
```

But, if I add the zebra striping as follows, then it overrides the red stripe.

```
$("#my_table tbody tr:even").addClass("stripeWhite");
$("#my_table tbody tr:odd").addClass("stripeBlack");
```

How do I skip the first row when zebra striping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add an exception to your selector for the first row using the jQuery [Not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$("#my_table tbody tr:even:not(:first)").addClass("stripeWhite");
$("#my_table tbody tr:odd").addClass("stripeBlack");
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7hBJ/2/) showing it in action.

OR you could set the first row color AFTER the striping.

Answer (score 1):

run this last:

```
$("#my_table tbody tr:first")
  .removeClass("stripeWhite")
  .removeClass("stripeBlack")
  .addClass("stripeRed");
```